# Putting SignIn and SignUp in single page using devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I just created a new rails app and added devise to it. Having different page for each sign in (users/sign_in) and sign up (users/sign_up) page is given by devise itself.  But i want to add both sign in and sign up form in single page of my custom controller (welcome/home).

And also I am really confused on how users controller is mapped to pages in views/devise/..and want to bring sign in and sign out pages under one roof.

Can anyone let me know directions on how to modify code to achieve this.

Comment: will they be separated forms?

Comment: yes ..and they will be placed side by side like in every regular sites...either you can sign in or sign up.

Comment: Well. You won't have a problem with the form. They'll be the same. The real problem here would be with the links, since devise will be expecting (devise/sessions/new.html.erb - sign in and devise/registrations/new - sign up). So, make sure to ensure the correct redirection. (See devise documentation for that)

Comment: i have somehow manage to put both forms side by side ..but here when i fill sign in form and try to sign in ..it redirects me to users/sign_in page ..which i dont want ..and i would like to be able to sign in from there itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And also I am really confused on how users controller is mapped to
>   pages in views/devise/

It isn't.

[Devise uses its own controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise) -

- `sessions_controller.rb` (for login / logout)
- `registrations_controller.rb` (for sign_up)
- `passwords_controller.rb` (for forgot etc)
- `confirmations_controller.rb` (for confirmations)
- `unlocks_controller.rb` (for invites, I believe)

When you call `devise_for` in your routes, it creates a series of routes which maps to these controllers. Indeed, [you can even override both the controllers and the paths themselves](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes):

```
devise_for :users, path: "auth", controllers: { sessions: "login" }, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'register', sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

This means that all the `devise` routing paths are actually formed from the `Devise` gem itself, not the `users` controller.

---

**Fix**

To fix your issue, you need to refer to the following - [Include Custom Sign-In Form Anywhere In Your App](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app)

Specifically, you'll need to use the following:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
 def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the `resource` for Devise wherever you want, which means you'll be able to use the forms where you want in your application.

Now, what I would *highly* recommend is to keep your devise forms in the same place. Don't change them. You want to **call them as partials**

Here's an example: http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk (login / register at top):

[image]

This is a development app we made a while back - it calls the login / register views as partials:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
...
<%= render "devise/sessions/new" %>
```

How you style it will be dependent on your CSS.

If you'd like more information, please let me know!

Comment: thanks for the clear information. One question.. when i encounter some error with either sign in and sing up page..it render /sign_in and /sign_up pages ..instead of showing errors there itself..why is that ?

Comment: @RahulDess, hi , hey I have ran into the same problem. Have you found the fix yet?